# Parsing data load in Pyspark/Databricks

Tags: xml, pyspark, databricks

I have over 5M xml files located in a GS bucket I want to parse in Pyspark.

I want to load the XML files maximizing the multiprocessing functionality of PySpark.
The code is the following :

def read_process_files(path):
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

```
# Parsing the XML files
df = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').option('rowTag', 'article').load(path)

# Apply the UDF to parse XML
df_parsed = df.withColumn('parsed_data', parse_xml_udf(col('body')))

# Add a boolean column verifying if the article is in the Pathway candidate list
df_parsed = df_parsed.withColumn("criteria", col("parsed_data.issn").isin(candidate_issn_list))

# Write to JSON files
json_dir = f'gs://setup/processed/articles/'
df_parsed.select(
    "parsed_data.article_title",
    "parsed_data.alt_title",
    "parsed_data.journal_title",
    "parsed_data.issn",
    "parsed_data.year",
    "parsed_data.abstract",
    "parsed_data.body",
    "parsed_data.uri",
    "parsed_data.doi",
    "criteria"
).write.mode("overwrite").format("json").option("ignoreNullFields", "false").save(json_dir)
```

```
read_process_files('gs://setup/raw/articles/xml_test*')
```

The problem is that the SOURCE DIR setup/raw/articles/xml_test cannot be loaded as it is too memory heavy.

I want to parse the loading process to run my code in chunks of 10.

I have tried different approaches without success and I do not want to iterate through files and load them individually. Any help would be welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try add this option while read the big file: .option("fetchsize", 20)

```
df = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').option('rowTag', 'article').option("fetchsize", 20).load(path)
```

Please let me know if this solve your problem, and if not, let me know too.

Comment: It did not work!

Comment: after loading the file paths as paths, I tried : 
##chunk_size = 400000

# Process files in chunks
##for i in range(0, len(paths), chunk_size):
  ##  chunk_files = paths[i:i + chunk_size]
  ##  read_process_files(chunk_files)

The problem now is that spark.read.format does not take path as argument...

Comment: can you provide what the error is?